# setting up Rspec

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run rspec on my machine for the first time. I did gem install rspec in the global gemset. However, when I try to do

```
  spec intranet_reader_spec.rb
```

I get

```
-bash: spec: command not found
```

And when I try to do

```
bundle exec rspec spec intranet_reader_spec.rb
```

I get

```
Could not locate Gemfile
```

(Note, I don't have a gemfile. I'm just running one test script from a ruby book)

I found these instructions for adding spec to the path, i.e. put the following in bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<UserName>/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin
```

However, that didn't work. I note that on my mac. if I navigate to .gem/ruby/1.8 and do 'ls', it doesn't have a 'bin.' In the 1.8 folder, it has

```
cache       doc     gems        specifications
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a `Gemfile` then you can't run `bundle exec`.

Also, the command for RSpec 2.x is `rspec`. You might be following an outdated tutorial, since the command was `spec` in version 1.x.

Just run:

```
rspec intranet_reader_spec.rb
```